# Can't Install Gems OSX Since Xcode 5DP4

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, osx-mountain-lion

I installed Xcode 5 DP 4 on my primary dev machine. It may be unrelated, but ever since, I have been unable to install any Ruby gems. If I type:

```
$ gem install rails
```

it just hangs. Same for any other gem. If I do a `ping` or a `traceroute` I get these results:

```
$ ping rubygems.org
PING rubygems.org (54.245.255.174): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
--- rubygems.org ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss

$ traceroute rubygems.org
traceroute to rubygems.org (54.245.255.174), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  cpe-76-176-148-1.san.res.rr.com (76.176.148.1)  25.744 ms  26.720 ms  29.172 ms
 2  tge1-2.crlscaij-cer01.socal.rr.com (76.166.18.105)  11.141 ms  25.128 ms  13.334 ms
 3  tge0-8-0-2.sndhcaax-ccr01.socal.rr.com (72.129.1.98)  19.853 ms  16.387 ms  16.660 ms
 4  agg22.lsancarc-ccr01.socal.rr.com (72.129.1.0)  16.843 ms  19.371 ms  20.137 ms
 5  107.14.17.132 (107.14.17.132)  16.329 ms  15.789 ms  15.733 ms
 6  66.109.9.24 (66.109.9.24)  17.291 ms  17.508 ms  18.562 ms
 7  las-bb1-link.telia.net (213.248.97.9)  16.518 ms
    las-bb1-link.telia.net (213.248.86.189)  17.344 ms  17.765 ms
 8  sjo-bb1-link.telia.net (213.155.134.103)  34.644 ms
    sjo-bb1-link.telia.net (213.155.137.63)  27.458 ms
    sjo-bb1-link.telia.net (213.248.80.16)  31.402 ms
 9  sea-b1-link.telia.net (213.155.134.81)  64.071 ms
    sea-b1-link.telia.net (213.155.136.69)  52.928 ms  54.107 ms
10  amazon-ic-151248-sea-b1.c.telia.net (213.248.94.30)  52.468 ms  49.540 ms  47.592 ms
11  205.251.225.184 (205.251.225.184)  51.268 ms
    205.251.225.178 (205.251.225.178)  48.527 ms
    205.251.225.184 (205.251.225.184)  93.230 ms
12  205.251.232.74 (205.251.232.74)  68.416 ms
    205.251.232.88 (205.251.232.88)  59.782 ms
    205.251.232.94 (205.251.232.94)  58.221 ms
13  205.251.232.153 (205.251.232.153)  56.725 ms
    205.251.232.147 (205.251.232.147)  59.429 ms
    205.251.232.153 (205.251.232.153)  62.639 ms
14  205.251.232.165 (205.251.232.165)  59.367 ms  56.984 ms  77.981 ms
15  ec2-50-112-0-159.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (50.112.0.159)  56.961 ms
    ec2-50-112-0-241.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (50.112.0.241)  58.880 ms
    ec2-50-112-0-249.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (50.112.0.249)  59.972 ms
16  *
```

I'll save you the junk after the 16th hop.

Question: What could be the issue here? DNS is resolving rubygems.org just fine because I can go right to the Web page. Any tips on installing gems again?

Oh, by the way, I did an `xcode-select -switch` to revert to my Xcode 4 frameworks and tools.

Thanks!

Comment: That host may just be configured not to respond to pings. What does gem install say if you ask it to be verbose (--verbose I think )

Comment: Same thing. I actually have --verbose in my .gemrc file. And I also checked that .gemrc for obsolete sources and the correct protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tracked it down after replying to Frederick Cheung's comment. In the .gemrc file, there was a reference to gems.rubyforge.org, and it was timing out. No other gem sources were being checked in the meantime.

Removing this source fixed the problem.